# Styling Dynamically added table headers and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I need to style a table added dynamically to my page by maybe changing the CSS settings/Styles. Somehow this has not work and I am looking for a way around this please. How do I resize table headers and columns for dynamically created tables?

Answer (score 0):

Check out jquery .css()

http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$("th").css( "width", value )
```

Jquery has some functions to dynamically change css properties.  There are also some functions for width

```
$("th").width( value )
```

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Invoke these functions after the table is added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have id's or classes you can just target them directly in css.  If they are being over ridden add an !important tag to them.

```
table#idhere {width:500px !important}
```

or

```
table.clashere {width:500px !important}
```

This will find the width of the table and then add it as an attribute so it will be set.

```
var tableWidth = $('#tbl_reportview table.report').width();
$('#tbl_reportview table.report').attr('width',tableWidth + 'px');
```

Comment: I have this specified in the CSS file but it does not seem to be working for me. #tbl_reportview table.report{width:auto;}

Comment: If I am understanding what you are asking the above code will work for you.